# Azure Synapse Analytics Powershell or CLI to provision Managed Private Endpoint

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-synapse

I have been struggling a lot to find Microsoft documentation on Azure Synapse Analytics to provision Managed Private Endpoints using powershell or CLI?

I can easily do it thru Azure Portal (basically thru Studio) but we want to do it as part of our Azure DevOps pipeline and provision the Managed Private endpoints (not the customer private endpoints) thru Powershell/CLI.

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: Did you already find out? I'm also searching. I'm wondering if this is part of the 'content' arm template that contains also pipelines, datasets, linked services etc.

Comment: Hi @SimonZeinstra, I spoke with Microsoft Architect Lalit Patel is his name and he told me that there is no CLI/PS for it yet (its coming but no known date yet). Also he suggested to us that since we still have to do APPROVAL for managed Pvt Endpoint manually it is better to do both i.e. Managed Pvt Endpoint creation and Approval thru portal since the ARM template, PS/CLI doesnt exists yet. This is straight from Microsoft so we are relying on that and doing it manually right now till something is published by Microsoft.

Comment: @SimonZeinstra also the only way we found was thru REST API programmatically which can be bundled if you want in powershell but we avoided that route and went with Microsoft's suggestion to keep it thru portal for now.

Comment: We were just able to create a managed endpoint using CLI and also did the approval on the data lake using CLI. I'll add an update to the answer from Swetha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the updated PowerShell module, there is now a powershell commandlet available: [New-AzSynapseManagedPrivateEndpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.synapse/new-azsynapsemanagedprivateendpoint?view=azps-6.4.0).

This should be the way to go. If you don't have PowerShell available, you can still use this CLI approach.

Comment: Thank you @simon-zeinstra

Answer (score 1):

Currently we don’t have native Synapse PowerShell and CLI commands for creating managed private endpoints. There is a workaround to create private endpoints through Azure CLI. The sample code is as below.

## Setup

```
$workspaceName = "your-workspace-name"
$synapseAnalyticsResourceId = "https://dev.azuresynapse.net"  
$managedVirtualNetworkName = "your-managed-virtual-network-name"
$newEndpointName = "your-new-endpoint-name"
```

## To list private endpoints

```
az rest --resource $synapseAnalyticsResourceId --method GET --url "https://$($workspaceName).dev.azuresynapse.net/managedVirtualNetworks/$($managedVirtualNetworkName)/managedPrivateEndpoints?api-version=2019-06-01-preview"
```

## To create private endpoints

[Doc for this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/data-plane/managed-private-endpoints/create)

```
# GroupId in the body is specifically for a Data Lake endpoint (Storage with Hierarchical namespace enabled)
$body = "{""properties"":{""privateLinkResourceId"": ""<resourceid-to-your-resource-for-endpoint>"", ""groupId"": ""dfs""}}" 
$body | Out-File body.json 
az rest --resource $synapseAnalyticsResourceId --method PUT --headers "Content-Type=application/json" --url "https://$($workspaceName).dev.azuresynapse.net/managedVirtualNetworks/$($managedVirtualNetworkName)/$($newEndpointName)?api-version=2019-06-01-preview" --body `@body.json 
Remove-Item body.json
```

Comment: That was very helpful, just some notes.

The PUT call needs to call nameofyourendpoint `https://$($workspaceName).dev.azuresynapse.net/managedVirtualNetworks/$($managedVirtualNetworkName)/nameofyourendpoint?api-version=2019-06-01-preview`. 

As a body we used the example from the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/data-plane/managed-private-endpoints/create#managedprivateendpointproperties)

Answer (score 1):

Additionally we have done the following to approve the Managed Endpoint connection. You need to have permissions on the resource that you are connecting to, if you want to be able to approve the Endpoint connection.

```
# list all private endpoints
endpointList = Get-AzPrivateEndpointConnection -PrivateLinkResourceId '/subscriptions/<xxx>/resourceGroups/<xxx>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<xxx>'
# filter the synapse endpoint
$synpapseEndpoint = $endpointList | Where-Object {     $_.PrivateEndpoint.Id.EndsWith('<yourworkspacename>.<yourmanagedenpointname>') }

Approve-AzPrivateEndpointConnection -ResourceId $synpapseEndpoint.Id
```