# Any PowerShell to enable/disable Azure Synapse Workspace Public network access to workspace endpoints?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-synapse

After going through the Microsoft documentation I haven't been able to find a way to automate the changing public network access settings for Azure Synapse. Any help would be amazing. I have seen it's possible for SQL servers and even ADF v2, so I believe there should also be availability for Synapse but nothing really I could find.
Any help would be great,
Joao

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please  [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the above requirement below is the workaround you may try:

***AFAIK,When we enabled managed virtual network meanwhile Public network access to be enabled automatically.***

we can use the PowerShell `cmdlts` to create managed  Virtual network for azure Synapse.

```
az synapse workspace create `
  --name $workspaceName `
  --resource-group $resourceGroupName `
  --storage-account $storageAccountName `
  --file-system $FileShareName `
  --sql-admin-login-user $sqlUserName `
  --sql-admin-login-password $sqlPassword `
  --location $regionName `
  --enable-managed-virtual-network true `//enabled managed virtual network
  --allowed-tenant-ids "Contoso"
```

[image]

For more information please refer the below links:

- [***Github|Create Azure Synapse Workspace with enabled Manged Identity***](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/synapse-analytics/how-to-move-workspace-from-one-region-to-another.md#create-an-azure-synapse-workspace-1)
- [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION| New-AzSynapseManagedVirtualNetworkConfig***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.synapse/new-azsynapsemanagedvirtualnetworkconfig?view=azps-7.3.0)

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this does not really solve the problem, as the synapse instance has already been created in bicep

Comment: Could you please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68087900/azure-synapse-analytics-powershell-or-cli-to-provision-managed-private-endpoint?rq=1